# TypeError: Function takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given kivy python

Tags: python, function, kivy, typeerror

I tried to add instance after the self, but still not working

this is the error message

```
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch

File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch

File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch

TypeError: sss() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

here is the full kivy python code

```
import kivy

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen



class Touch(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1

        self.Rc1 = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)

        self.Rc1.bind(on_press=self.sss)

        self.add_widget(self.Rc1)


    def sss(self):

        self.Rc1 = Button(text="Push Me !",

                          font_size="20sp",

                          background_color=[1, 0, 0, 1],

                          color=(1, 1, 1, 1),

                          size=(32, 32),

                          size_hint=(.2, .2),

                          pos=(300, 250))

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Touch()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error message traceback.

Comment: File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
 TypeError: sss() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Just add `,*args` to the args list of `sss()`.

Comment: thanks, John Anderson, the error message is gone, but my function inside the sss still not executing or in another way, my button doesn't change its color.

Comment: when you press `Button` then it sends some information (`event`) to executed function and your function should get it.

Comment: if you want to change color then don't create new button but change color in existing button. BTW: if you create button and assing to the same variable then it doesn't replace existing button - you would have to remove old button and use again `add_widget(self.Rc1)`

Comment: how can I change the color after clicking the button? it should be inside the function

Comment: you have `self.Rc1` to access existing button and change its values - probably `self.Rc1.color = ...`

Comment: thanks, furas, that solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click button then it executes your function with some information. In different GUIs it can use different information. In some GUIs it can be info about event, in others it can be info about widget, etc.

`Kivy` sends information about clicked widget and you have to receive it

```
def sss(self, widget):
```

---

If you want to change existing `Button` then don't create new button - it will not change existing if you assing it to the same variable. You would have to remove old button and add new button using `add_widget()`

You have existing button in `self.Rc1` so you can do

```
def sss(self, widget):
    self.Rc1.text = "Push Me !"
    self.Rc1.font_size = "20sp"
    self.Rc1.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
    self.Rc1.color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.Rc1.size = (32, 32)
    self.Rc1.size_hint = (.2, .2)
    self.Rc1.pos = (300, 250)
```

But more interesting is that you get also this widget in `sss(self, widget):` and you can do

```
def change_button(self, widget):
    widget.text = "Push Me !"
    widget.font_size = "20sp"
    widget.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
    widget.color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    widget.size = (32, 32)
    widget.size_hint = (.2, .2)
    widget.pos = (300, 250)
```

This way you can use the same function with different buttons

[image]

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Touch(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        #self.all_buttons = []
        
        for row in range(10):
            for col in range(10):
                x = col * 100
                y = row * 100
                button = Button(text=f"{row},{col}", pos = (x, y))
                button.bind(on_press=self.change_button)
                
                self.add_widget(button)
                
                #self.all_buttons.append(button)

    def change_button(self, widget):
        if widget.background_color == [1,1,1,1]:
            widget.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
        else:
            widget.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Touch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```